# Highlight <p:inputText> using PrimeFaces validation

Tags: java, spring, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to highlight `<p:inputText>` based on some condition but eventually I got nothing.
Here is my xhtml code:

```
<p:inputText value="#{loginTo.userName}" id="username" required="true" label="username" maxlength="20"  requiredMessage="#{appLoginParameter['AppLoginNameRequiredMsg']}">
</p:inputText>
```

Here is my Java Code:

```
ResourceBundle appLoginBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("app/AppLogin");
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        UIComponent uiComponent = UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(facesContext);
        String message = "";
        try{
            message = appLoginBundle.getString(userLoginDetailTO.getLoginRemarks());
        }catch(Exception exp){
            message =appLoginBundle.getString("UnknownException");
        }
        FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage(message);
        facesMessage.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        facesContext.addMessage("", facesMessage);
        UIInput username= (UIInput) uiComponent.getAttributes().get("username");
        username.setValid(false);
```

But I'm getting Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: Where are you getting the null pointer at?

Comment: UIInput password = (UIInput) uiComponent.getAttributes().get("password"); in this line'

Comment: Now since that is the first time you call uiComponent. Is your uiComponent null? Also, `UIInput password = (UIInput) uiComponent.getAttributes().get("password");` is actually `UIInput password = (UIInput) uiComponent.getAttributes().get("username");`in your code provided. That might cause some confusion...

Comment: oh sorry my bad. But i Initialize my uiComponent. like this UIComponent uiComponent = UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(facesContext); is it right way iam not sure about it

Comment: Okay, I posted an answer. Hopefully it helps you! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public UIComponent findComponent(final String id){
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
    UIViewRoot root = context.getViewRoot();
    final UIComponent[] found = new UIComponent[1];
    root.visitTree(new FullVisitContext(context), new VisitCallback() {     
        @Override
        public VisitResult visit(VisitContext context, UIComponent component) {
            if(component.getId().equals(id)){
                found[0] = component;
                return VisitResult.COMPLETE;
            }
            return VisitResult.ACCEPT;              
        }
    });
    return found[0];

}
```

This code will find only the first component in the tree with the id you pass. You will have to do something custom if there are 2 components with the same name in the tree (this is possible if they are under 2 different naming containers) or you could also set `prependId="false"` in your form.